# syntax in function in c++ class

Tags: c++, class, arduino

I am creating a simple c++ class to manage a series of menu items.
Each menu item has:

1. an LED pin
2. a display buffer
3. a state

I'd like to init the class and save a different display buffer (a single INT)
for each menu. An object will be instantiated for each menu item.

There should be set, get and put functions

set will store the address of the INT buffer
get will return the value stored in the INT buffer
put will place a new value in the INT buffer

Here follows simplified-psudeo code of how I think the set function would be done:

```
class menuMgr() {

    /* this should save the address of the buffer in the class object /*
       void set_displaybuff(&buffer) {
          _buf = buffer;
       }
```

I'm need help with the c++ syntax for the get and set functions, where _buf
is the private var that holds the data.

=Alan R.

Comment: Wow - didn't realize I'd worded my question so badly.  I DO know C - have been programming 30 years... just need a little help with pointers.  Needless to say - I'll certainly avoid such pitfalls in the future.  Reply I got DID help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to declare your class

```
class MenuMgr
{
private:
   buffer _buf;
public:
   void set_displaybuff(buffer &buffer)
  {
     _buf= buffer;     
  }
};
```

This is just the simplest example imaginable. But you have to implement Constructor and Destructor and add the included´s needed.

Comment: I understand the class syntax - had just lost my way on using pointers. Your answer is what I was trying to figure out - thanks!

Comment: Nothing for that man.